# Crystal Reports - RTF vs HTML

Tags: html, crystal-reports, rtf

Estou gerando vários relatório com Crystal Reports, e como pude perceber existem basicamente duas formas de interpretar texto formatado (RTF e HTML).

Levando em consideração os **diferentes estilos**, as várias tags do HTML, qual seria a opção que oferece **maior suporte** e rapidez na interpretação pelo Crystal Reports?